# jQuery change submit value to "Please wait" & then submit the form using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form.

```
            <form action="login.php" method="post" id="form">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="textbox" id="name" placeholder="Username"><br /><br />
                <input type="password" name="pass" class="textbox" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br /><br />
                <div id="holder">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="submit_wide">
                </div>
                <br />
            </form>
```

I want to change the value of the submit input to "Please wait.." upon click. So while the page is redirecting, user will see "Please wait..".

**I don't want to POST using javascript, I want it to redirect.**

*When I click 'Login', it changes to 'Please wait', but the submit action stops, but when I click again, it redirects.*

***What's wrong and how do I fix this?***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submit_wide").click(function() 
            {
                if ($("#name").val() != '' && $("#pass").val() != '')
                {
                    $("#holder").html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please wait.." class="submit_wide">');
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#error").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#error").html('<span class="alert alert-error">Please fill ALL of the fields.</span>');
                    event.preventDefault();                 
                }
            });
        });
```

**What I've tried:**

*Adding*

```
$("#form").submit();
```

after the HTML change line.

It' just does the same as it did before.

How do I fix this and what causing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".submit_wide").click(function (event) {
    if ($("#name").val() != '' && $("#pass").val() != '') {
        $(this).val('Please wait..');
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#error").html('<span class="alert alert-error">Please fill ALL of the fields.</span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not what I actually wanted.
This cancels the submiting at all, now I can't even submit on the second attempt. I want the value to change to "please wait" and then redirect to the page, and not stop the submiting process.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
$("#holder").html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please wait.." class="submit_wide">');
```

with

```
$('.submit_wide').val('please wait..');
```

when you use `html()`, it removes your submit button and creates a new one. You should only change the value of the button.

Answer (score 0):

To make it submit you will need to return true from the submit handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submit_wide").click(function() 
            {
                if ($("#name").val() != '' && $("#pass").val() != '')
                {
                    $("#holder").html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please wait.." class="submit_wide">');
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#error").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#error").html('<span class="alert alert-error">Please fill ALL of the fields.</span>');            
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

ps I would just change the value of the submit not replace the whole button.

Comment: How do I just change the value?

Answer (score 0):

Make this your html script:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="form" onSubmit="return replaceIt()" >
                <input type="text" name="name" class="textbox" id="name" placeholder="Username"><br /><br />
                <input type="password" name="pass" class="textbox" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br /><br />
                <div id="holder">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="submit_wide">
                </div>
                <br />
            </form>
```

And this your JS function:

```
function replaceIt() {
            if ($("#name").val() != '' && $("#pass").val() != '')
            {
                $("#holder").html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please wait.." class="submit_wide">');
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $("#error").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#error").html('<span class="alert alert-error">Please fill ALL of the fields.</span>');
                return false;              
            }
    }
```